# Javascript Jquery: extract string from value and compose URL with this string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url, extract

I am using an autocomplete Javascript function, and I need to extract the last 5 characters from 'value' and then compose URL for onSelect.

The function I am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options, a;
    jQuery(function(){
      var onAutocompleteSelect = function(value, data) {
          window.open('ITEM.PRO?id='+ value);
        }

      options = { 
      serviceUrl:'JQUERY-SEARCH.pro',
      onSelect: onAutocompleteSelect,
       };
      a = $('#query').autocomplete(options);

    });
    </script>
```

When I click on search result it loads "ITEM.PRO?id=Article Brand Model Year Description 35612", but I need load "ITEM.PRO?id=35612"

Please could you help me? I am a totally newbie with JS.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please post a sample output from `JQUERY-SEARCH.pro`. Is it sending a separate `data` array, besides for the `suggestions` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var onAutocompleteSelect = function(value, data) {
          window.open('ITEM.PRO?id='+ value.substring(value.length-5));
        }
```

Comment: it works perfect! Thank you very much. I need only the last 5 characters of the string. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `window.open('ITEM.PRO?id='+ value);` could you do this?

```
window.open('ITEM.PRO?id='+ value.split(' ').pop());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to acheive this.

This simplest is to add

```
value = value.slice(-5);
```

right before

```
window.open('ITEM.PRO?id='+ value);
```

This sets `value` to its last 5 characters. Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) about the `String.slice` function.

If you want set the value to the last 'word', so to speak, delimited by spaces, you could do this instead:

```
value = value.split(" ").pop();
```

Another method would be to take the last continuous string of digits in the value. For that, you could use this:

```
value = value.match(/\d+/).pop();
```

Which method you use, of course, depends on what would work most reliably with the input you have.

Comment: @bozodz I thought that too, but he only asked for the last five digits. Maybe he knows that the id will always be five digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible solution, but will work in the case you listed. I will edit if you post more details:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options, a;
    jQuery(function(){
      var onAutocompleteSelect = function(value, data) {
          window.open('ITEM.PRO?id='+ value.match(/\d+/)[0]);
        }

      options = { 
      serviceUrl:'JQUERY-SEARCH.pro',
      onSelect: onAutocompleteSelect,
       };
      a = $('#query').autocomplete(options);

    });
</script>
```

`value.match(/\d+/)[0]` will match any digits in your string as any array, so we take the first item in that array.

Answer (score 0):

When your IDs exceed 5 digits, your code will break (as has been stated in comments). You can also use the `.split` approach mentioned by @bordoz, the disadvantage being that spaces in any of the other words would break this solution. Or you could use:

```
var url = 'ITEM.PRO?id='+ value.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'');
```

Which would fail only if any of the other word contain numbers. Which one best fits your situation?

Comment: Splits in other words wouldn't break bozdoz's solution, because he is taking the last token, delimited by spaces. That means it doesn't matter how many items separated by spaces there are, as long as the id is the last one.

Comment: @Peter - true :) I had somehow failed to see that.